# Cambiar color de JButton dinámico

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente código, pero el mismo no cambia de color, el fondo es blanco.

```
private void cargarMesas(Usuario u) {
  int indice = 0 ;
  Mozo mozoaux = (Mozo)u ;

  this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,9));
  while(indice<mozoaux.getListadoMesas().size()) {

     JButton boton = new JButton(mozoaux.getListadoMesas().get(indice).getNumeroMesa()+"");

     agregarBoton(boton);
     indice++;
  }
}

private void agregarBoton(JButton jButton) {
    JButton aux = jButton;
    aux.setBackground(Color.red);
    aux.setEnabled(false);

    this.add(aux);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con:

`aux.setBackground(new Color(255,50,50);`

quizas asi ya te cambie de color, sino intenta poner el `this.add(aux);`
bajo de `JButton aux = jButton;`

Comment: lo probare , gracias

Comment: no cambia de color asi tampoco gracias igual

Answer (score 0):

En vista de que mi respuesta anterior no te funciono, decidi hacer una prueba yo mismo y escribiendo este codigo:

```
javax.swing.JButton boton = new javax.swing.JButton("Hola mundo");
boton.setLocation(100,100);
boton.setSize(100,50);
boton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,50,50));
this.add(boton);
```

Me funciono, agrego un botón de color rojo al formulario, quizas hay algo distinto, incluso el orden de las lineas puede afectar.

Otra opción podría ser que le des click derecho al proyecto y des click en "clean" o "limpiar", en ocasiones me ha pasado que algo debería de funcionar y esta bien escrito y todo, pero no funciona entonces limpio el proyecto y en más de una ocasión eso me ha solucionado la molestia.

Comment: Probare asi , talvez algo que pueda afectar es que uso MAC , aunque probare tu codigo y te comento que tal gracias

Comment: He probado el siguiente codigo boton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,50,50)); Pero solo cambiar el color del borde, no el fondo. '??

Answer (score 0):

Puedes asignar un color de fondo a un botón ***java Swing*** con el método **setBackground()**.

Lo más sencillo es asignar al botón un color de fondo por defecto y controlar si cambia mediante una propiedad booleana.

Ejemplo de botón que cambia alternativamente de color.

```
package swing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;


public class MutableColoredButton extends JFrame {

    final private JButton btn = new JButton("Click Me");
    final private ButtonsListener bl = new ButtonsListener();

    private static boolean defaultColor = true;


    /**
     * Main method: 
     * @param args 
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new MutableColoredButton().setVisible( true );
    }

    /**
     * Contruct
     * 
     */
    public MutableColoredButton() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        setSize(300, 230);
        setTitle("Button test");

        this.setButton();
    }

    private void setButton() {
        // Set buttons size
        // setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension)
        // Dimension(float width, float height)
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 60));

        // Add a default backgroung color to the button
        btn.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        // Add listener to the button
        btn.addActionListener(bl);

        // Add the button to the frame
        add(btn);
    }


    class ButtonsListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            System.out.println("Button clicked !"); // HACK: trace

            if (defaultColor) {
                defaultColor = false;
                btn.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            } else {
                defaultColor = true;
                btn.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }    
        }

    } //class ButtonsListener

} // class
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]